# How to make vscode work with global namespace?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

This is for JavaScript project.

Say I have two files:

```
// a.js
Abc.foo = function(x) { return x; };

// b.js
Abc.foo(1);
```

What can I do, e.g. configure `jsconfig.json` in some way, so that [F12] on `b.js` `Abc.foo` will jump to `a.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature request for Salsa, tracking at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7632